# How to hook into save! with rails before_save! callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

Is there a way to hook into the `save!` with a callback?

I am looking for something like:

```
class CompositeService < Service
  attr_accessible :subservices

  before_save :save_subservices
  before_save :save_subservices! if bang_save?

  private

  def save_subservices
    @subservices.each(&:save)
  end

  def save_subservices!
    @subservices.each(&:save!)
  end
end
```

Where a `save!` is cascaded and calls `save!` on the (faux) association `subservices`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder: is this extra logic even necessary?

If the `save` method on each of your `@subservices` obeys the ActiveRecord `save` semantics, then you probably will get the correct behavior for free.

In other words, make sure your `save` methods return `true` or `false` for success or failure. Then, the composite code becomes as simple as this:

```
class CompositeService < Service
  attr_accessible :subservices

  before_save :save_subservices

  private

  def save_subservices
    @subservices.all?(&:save)
  end
end
```

If any of your sub services fail to save, then the `save_subservices` callback will return `false`, which will abort the callback chain. This will cause the wrapping `save` to return `false`. And in the case of `save!`, it will raise an exception.

```
composite.save
# => false

composite.save!
# => ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved
```

Comment: Makes sense. With an additional `after_validate` to validate all the `@subservices` you'll have the full AR behaviour back: `valid?`, `errors` and halting the save in situations when an "association" cannot be saved. Good one.

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can do this, but I would advise not to use this approach in production because it can change in newer rails. And it is just wrong.

You can inspect call stack of your before callback and check if there is save! method.

```
class CompositeService < Service
  before_save :some_callback

  def some_callback
    lines = caller.select { |line| line =~ /persistence.rb/ && line =~ /save!/ }

    if lines.any?
      @subservices.each(&:save!)
    else
      @subservices.each(&:save)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Interesting hack! Certainly. But I won't consider a hack like this production-worthy. Still: a creative and unexpected angle. Thanks.

Comment: Are you calling `save` or `save!` method in your own code? Maybe you can change your design a bit and not use callbacks. You can create additional methods like `save_with_bang` and it will call `save!` as well as `@subservices.each(&:save!)`

Answer (score 0):

Look at ActiveRecord autosave attribute:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html

Comment: As I made clear in my example, the association is not an `Arel` association. Are you suggesting that instead, I should turn this "faux" association into a real one? And if so, how would I do that, without a) introducing a large public inferface of association methods and b) don't have the database-columns for foreign keys?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that it wasn't a real model.  I wouldn't put in the bang variant as your before_save callback will be called in both cases automatically by ActiveRecord.  I.E.  if it's save or save!, the before_save callback will be invoked.  All you have to ensure is that you populate self.errors << [:subservices, "what went wrong"] in case of failure and ActiveModel will raise appropriately